# How to change char in tuple

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, tuples

I have a variable with students information and i need to change their score with number.
for example if students score is between 51 and 60 their new number should be 6 and etc.

```py
example_scores=[('Ann', 92), ('Bob', 55), ('Donna', 30)]
def process_scores(scores: list, threshold: int=None) -> list:
  for i in scores:
    for x in i:
      if isinstance(x, int):
        if 51 <=  x <= 60:
          y = list(i)
          y[1] = 6
          i = tuple(y)
  return  scores

res = process_scores(example_scores, example_threshold)
print(res)
```

so this is code i have at the moment, but somehow when make return of scores its not changed.
if i return --y-- it returns just `(bob,6)`
it doesnt even show errors.

Comment: Please post your code using proper code formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

```
def process_scores(scores: list, threshold: int=None) -> list:
  for index, i in enumerate(scores):
    for x in i:
      if isinstance(x, int):
        if 51 <=  x <= 60:
          y = list(i)
          y[1] = 6
          scores[index] = y
  return  scores

res = process_scores(example_scores, example_threshold)
print(res)
```

Or even better, if the structure of the list is consistent (not sure how you want to use threshold):

```
def process_scores(scores: list, threshold: int=None) -> list:
    return map(lambda x: 6 if 51 <= x[1] <= 60 else x, scores)
```